# question: how to make an action request to ompl_planning

Tags: ros, path-planning, action, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
has someone an example or a detailed explanation on how yo make a request to the ompl_planning node? (the type of message, how is it filled and sent, how to interpret the response and get the trayectory path, etc).

Particularly I was following the [arm_navigation Tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Components%20Visualizer) and for what I see in rxgraph, the ompl_planning node is the one calculating the trayectory, but what I'm actually interested in, is to get each of the configuration points of the generated path.

I'll be very thankfull for any help in this matter :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32430/question:-how-to-make-an-action-request-to-ompl_planning/) by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

arm planning has been replaced by MoveIt!

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2